# Document.write is not working in Ie9 standard mode

Tags: extjs4

here I have some sample code which is working in chrome and Firefox, but not working in IE.

test.html:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sdk/extjs4.2/resources/css/ext-all.css">   <script type="text/javascript" src="sdk/extjs4.2/ext-all.js"></script>
<script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

test.js:

```
 Ext.onReady(function(){
        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        title: 'My First Panel',
        frame: true,
        width: 400,
        height: 400,
        html : '<iframe id="iframe-test"'+
        ' style="overflow:auto;width:100%;height:100%;"'+
        ' frameborder="0" '+
        ' src="about.html"'+
        '></iframe>',
        items : [{
        xtype : 'button',
        text : 'test',
        handler : function(){
            var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe-test');
             iframe = (iframe.contentWindow) ? iframe.contentWindow : (iframe.contentDocument.document) ? iframe.contentDocument.document : iframe.contentDocument;
            var doc = iframe.document;
             doc.open();
             var content = '<html><head> </head>'+
                            '<body>'+
                            '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sdk/extjs4.2/resources/css/ext-all.css">'+
                            '<script type="text/javascript" src="sdk/extjs4.2/ext-all.js"></script>'+
                            '<div id="my-div" class="x-hidden" style="background-color:red;width:100px;height:50px;"></div>'+
                            '<style> .body{ }</style> '+
                            ' <script>Ext.onReady(function() {'+
                            'Ext.Msg.alert("coming fine");'+
                            '});</script></body>'+
                            '</html>';
            //console.log(content);
            doc.write(content);
            doc.close();
        }
        }],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
    });
```

Can any body help where am missing? what i need to do to make it work

Thanks 
Tapaswini

Comment: document.write is obsolete and should not be used. Use DOM methods instead.